# AST - Restricting user input containing python code to prevent reading files

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, security, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm creating a server using netcat and python which lets users to connect and run arbitrary python code if it's less than 100 lines. The goal is to prevent users from reading files on the server. To achieve this goal, I'm using ast. Users can input their code:

```
code = ""
cntr = 0
while cntr < 100:
      line = sys.stdin.readline()
      code += line
      cntr = cntr + 1
```

Then, code variable is passed to compile:

```
astobj = compile(code, "server.py", 'exec', flags=ast.PyCF_ONLY_AST)
```

Is using the following code safe and effective to prevent users from reading sensitive files?

```
def check(comp):
  for c in ast.walk(comp):
    match type(c):
      case (ast.Call|ast.Import|ast.ImportFrom):
        return False
  return True

if check(astobj):
   exec(compile(code, "server.py", 'exec'))
```

Answer (score 5):

It is not safe code! I have confirmed that atleast 160+ people have bypassed this code to read local files.

PS!

We are watching you!